# List movie info in columns that collapse into one column

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-lists, html-table

I'm trying to show movie info for a website, but I'm having issues with the CSS and HTML.  I want the title (Director:, Cast:, etc) to be in line with the first item in the list, and then have all others follow below. I tried a definition list, but couldn't figure out the css to make it responsive. Now I have a table, but I'm starting to suspect a regular list might be better.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joeptqLy/) which looks how I want it to when the window is wide enough, but gets ruined when shrunk down to mobile (which is when I want the Cast: columns to become one column)

Any help would be super appreciated, I've been playing with this for months.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="movieinfo">
    <table>
      <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td class="workheader">Director:</td>
        <td>John Carney</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td class="workheader">Writer:</td>
        <td>John Carney</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="workheader">Cast:</td>
        <td>Keira Knightly</td>
        <td class="spacedRight">James Corden</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Mark Ruffalo</td>
        <td class="spacedRight">CeeLo Green</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Hailee Steinfeld</td>
        <td class="spacedRight">Catherine Keener</td>
      </tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Adam Levine</td>
    </table>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
.movieinfo {
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are partially misusing the table for layout here by putting the cast names in separate cells. Don't let your design requirements influence your decision on how to markup the data. This includes using appropriate HTML elements such as `<th>` for header cells:

```
<div class="movieinfo">
    <table>
        <tr class="spaceUnder">
            <th>Director:</th>
            <td>John Carney</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="spaceUnder">
            <th>Writer:</th>
            <td>John Carney</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Cast:</th>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>Keira Knightly</li>
                    <li>James Corden</li>
                    <li>Mark Ruffalo</li>
                    <li>CeeLo Green</li>
                    <li>Hailee Steinfeld</li>
                    <li>Catherine Keener</li>
                    <li>Adam Levine</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

To format the cast in columns there are two options depending on if you want to order the items primely vertically or horizontally. For vertical ordering use [columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/columns):

```
.movieinfo ul {
    -webkit-columns: 3 10em;
    -moz-columns: 3 10em;
    columns: 3 10em;
}
```

EDIT: When using both a width and a number form `columns`, then the number is the maxmium number of columns displayed. The gap between the columns can be set with [`column-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap).

More complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/owdz2m0m/

Or for horizontal use floats:

```
.movieinfo ul > li  {
    float: left;
    width: 10em;
}
```

EDIT: Limiting the number of columns with floats is a bit trickier. You'll need to set the `max-width` of the surrounding element (in this case the `ul`) to the "column width * maximum Number of columns". So to limit the columns to 2 set `.movieinfo ul { max-width: 20em; }`

More complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/tr9e8bmv/

In either case you can use media queries at adjust the widths depending on screen size.

Comment: This is awesome thanks so much RoToRa!  That second example works great, and I'll add the media queries like you said. One question: how do I stop it from expanding to more than two columns (a long short window spreads it out into one line), and also, how do i reduce the gap space in between the two columns. Again, thanks for all your help, I've been trying to solve this forever.

Comment: @Acoustic77 I've added some edits that should answer your questions.

Comment: RoToRa you are the absolute best, everything looks amazing now and you taught me about the max and min width for controlling elements + columns, so I was able to do some other cool stuff with that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I think, You need `@media` queries. Something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px){ your style }
```

And You can build your HTML width `<dl>` and `<ul>`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gw6utfvw/)

If You change window size on demo, You can see how 2 columns become 1 column. [Screen 1](http://prntscr.com/4hw0fo), [Screen 2](http://prntscr.com/4hw0iu)